# Python datetime without Y-M-D

Tags: python

I'm converting an string type of Time series to datetime in Python and I'm so confused that why is my datetime always display the result I don't expect. \n

what I want is shown in my img [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G58rY.jpg)

Comment: A **date**time pairs a date and a time. If you don't want a date, maybe don't convert to a datetime?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

time = '23:30:00' # Time in string format
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')
print(dt.time()) # time method will only return the time
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should put your question in the question, not some off-site illustration. We do have code blocks available. Also, you converted to Pandas datetime, not Python datetime. Both of these have "date" in their name because they do contain the date. You could represent just a time using e.g. Pandas `timedelta` or Python `datetime.time`. The format you pass to `panads.to_datetime` is how to parse the input, not how to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have converted your string `Series` to a `Series` of `pd.Timestamp`. Internally a `Timestamp` is a number of nanoseconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

The correct way to format a date in pandas is to convert it to a string with `.dt.strfime`, *when you no longer need to process it as a `Timestamp`.

TL/DR:

- if you want it in `HH:MM:SS` format leave it in string dtype
- if you need to process it as a `Timestamp`and yet have it in `HH:MM:SS` format, convert it to Timestamp, process it and when done convert it back to a string